# Load different javascript only for smartphones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript code that swaps background image on scroll down, but I had some troubles with the debounce, so I set different debounce times for different browsers (I know it's a bad thing to spoof browsers, but I'm new to javascript and it does the job for now).

But there's another thing, when I scroll on my phone, it scrolls way too fast, so I wanted to set another debounce time for screens smaller than 480px. It didn't work.
I think it's because the "browser if" overwrites the "width if", but not sure how to fix it.

Here's the code (I know it's poorly written, I'm still new to javascript) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';  
    var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;   

    var numberofscroll = 0;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var dontHandle = false;
    $("#home").scroll(function () {
    if (dontHandle) return;
        dontHandle = true;
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        (st > lastScrollTop) ? numberofscroll++ : numberofscroll--;
        console.log(numberofscroll);
        console.log(lastScrollTop);
        console.log(st);
        if (numberofscroll<2){
            change_background2(numberofscroll);
        }
        else if (numberofscroll<3){
            change_background3(numberofscroll);
        }
        else if (numberofscroll<4){
            change_background4(numberofscroll);
        }
        else if (numberofscroll<5){
            change_background5(numberofscroll);
        }
        else if (numberofscroll<6){
            change_background6(numberofscroll);
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;
        if (isFirefox == true) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            dontHandle = false;
        }, 150);
        }else if (isOpera == true) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            dontHandle = false;
        }, 10);
        }else if (isChrome == true) {
             window.setTimeout(function() {
            dontHandle = false;
        }, 10);
        }else if ($(window).width() < 480){
         window.setTimeout(function() {
         dontHandle = false;
        }, 500);
        }else { 
            window.setTimeout(function() {
            dontHandle = false;
        }, 50);
        }
    });

/images swaping code here/

});
```

added this, didn't work:

```
    if ($(window).width() < 480){
     window.setTimeout(function() {
     dontHandle = false;
    }, 500);
    }else { 
    window.setTimeout(function() {
     dontHandle = false;
    }, 50);
    }
```

Comment: I think you can do this, but it depends on your server technology.

Comment: @bto.rdz sorry for noob question, but what does "my server technology" mean?

Comment: Have the `else if` for your `$(window).width() < 480` be it's own separate *if-statement*.

Comment: Just by the way: look at switch statements instead of chains of if/else http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: @DeneaNovac asp.net, node js, I only know asp.net and you can detect if it is a mobile device and then send a script according to client

Comment: @bto.rdz You don't need a server to handle this task, they are just looking at the window width.

Comment: @BenPhilipp Yes, although I think it might even be a better idea to use a loop.

Comment: Also remember that when dealing with new hi res phone screens, pixels-per-inch is important to account for...

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek followed your answer, the whole changing script stopped working, update with the code I pasted, can you please check.

Comment: @DeneaNovac Remove it out of the entire `if-else if-else` items and place it as a `if` afterwards.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I did, didn't work, here's the code now http://jsfiddle.net/42e3mt4v/

Comment: @DeneaNovac Oh, I didn't notice you where setting timeouts. In that case just move it to be the first item in your *if-elseif-else*.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek as first item it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is based on the *if-else if-else* structure works. If any of them are true, then the reset of the items are not evaluated. So if you are using Chrome and have a width of say 300px:

```
if (isFirefox == true) {
  ...
}else if (isOpera == true) {
  ..
}else if (isChrome == true) {
  ...
}else if ($(window).width() < 480){
 ...
}else { 
  ...
}
```

It will stop at `isChrome == true` being `true` and skip the rest, meaning you never did the browser width check. To fix that simply have the width check be done first. This way it will always check the width first, and then check what browser it is next.

```
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
  ...
}else if (isOpera == true) {
  ..
}else if (isChrome == true) {
  ...
}else if (isFirefox == true){
 ...
}else { 
  ...
}
```